# What are the modes of vibration of a genus-2 surface?

Tags: general-topology, harmonic-analysis, spherical-harmonics

So it's spherical harmonics for a sphere.
The vibrations of a torus presumably are just ordinary string harmonics around each loop.
But what are the harmonics on a genus-2 surface (a donut with 2 holes).

Or more for that matter. Has this been solved?

Comment: I think, although I never studied this, that the modes of vibrations depend on the differential properties or the surface thus for different genus-2 surfaces The modes of vibrations should be different. Maybe your question should be about a particular genus-2 surface, for example bolza surface which according to Wikipedia is the most symmetric genus 2 surface in some sense.